# Nuxt-img with Nuxt 3 build - can't load any images

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, vuejs3, nuxtjs3

I tried to approach the topic from two directions:

1. i have images in assets/ folder. When I used the dir variable in nuxt.config.ts in the development environment everything works fine, but after npm run build on the hosting no image loads and the path to images still directs to the public/ folder.
2. according to the documentation, I put all the photos into the public/ folder without any dir variable in nuxt.config.ts and on the development environment everything works fine, but after npm run dev on the hosting again no photo loads, although the path seems correct.

```
IPX Error: Error: File not found (/app/.output/public/images/helpers/elements/vectors/dollar2.png)
```

Has anyone encountered a similar problem and knows how to solve this problem?

### nuxt.config.ts

```
export default defineNuxtConfig({
image: {
    presets: {
      default: {
        modifiers: {
          format: 'webp',
          loading: 'lazy',
          quality: "100"
        }
      }
    }
  }
})
```

Comment: Ok, i found a solution for my problem no. 2. Just set a provider in nuxt.config.ts to IPX and it's work for me

Comment: can you explain this solution you have achieved? I am facing the exact same problem.